# TypeError: User.comparePassword is not a function. Comes up with Postman

Tags: express, syntax-error

I'm trying to get my login component on the server side to work, but it keeps giving me this one error over and over. "TypeError: User.comparePassword is not a function" I had it working in postman before, but I can't figure out why it broke now. I'm making an ecommerce site, so I'm excluding code that has stuff to do with the rest of the site.

[user.js - my routing and where the error is being presented.]

```
const { User, validateUser } = require("../models/user.js");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const config = require("config");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

//get users
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    return res.send(users);
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(500).send(`Internal server Error: ${ex}`);
  }
});

//get a user
router.get("/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);
    return res.send(user);
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(500).send(`Internal server Error: ${ex}`);
  }
});

//new user
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { error } = validateUser(req.body);

    if (error) return res.status(500).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user = new User({
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt),
    });

    await user.save();

    const token = jwt.sign(
      { _id: user._id, name: user.name },
      config.get("jwtSecret")
    );

    return res
      .header("x-auth-token", token)
      .header("access-control-expose-headers", "x-auth-token")
      .send({ _id: user._id, name: user.name, email: user.email });
  } catch (ex) {
    return res.status(500).send(`InternalServerError:${ex}`);
  }
});

router.get("/auth", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    _id: req.user._id,
    isAdmin: req.user.role === 0 ? false : true,
    isAuth: true,
    email: req.user.email,
    name: req.user.name,
    role: req.user.role,
    image: req.user.image,
    cart: req.user.cart,
    history: req.user.history,
  });
});

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
    if (!User)
      return res.json({
        loginSuccess: false,
        message: "Auth failed, email not found",
      });
    });
  

    User.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (!isMatch)
        return res.json({ loginSuccess: false, message: "Wrong password" });

      user.generateToken((err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        res.cookie("w_authExp", User.tokenExp);
        res.cookie("w_auth", User.token).status(200).json({
          loginSuccess: true,
          userId: user._id,
        });
      });
    });

router.get("/logout", auth, (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { token: "", tokenExp: "" },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
      return res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
      });
    }
  );
});
});
```

[User.js - Userschema]

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Joi = require('joi');
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('config');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { productSchema } = require('./Product');
const { reviewSchema } = require('./review');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 255},
    password: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 1024, minlength: 5},
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    cart: {type: [productSchema], default: []},
    newSalePost: {type: [productSchema], default: []},
    review: {type: [reviewSchema], default: []},
    image: {type: String, required: true}
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    return jwt.sign({_id: this._id, name: this.name, isAdmin: this.isAdmin}, config.get('jwtSecret'));
};

function validateUser(user){
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
        password: Joi.string().min(5).max(1024).required(),
    });
    return schema.validate(user);

}

userSchema.statics.findByToken = function (token, cb) {
    var user = this;

    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', function (err, decode) {
        user.findOne({ "_id": decode, "token": token }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            cb(null, user);
        })
    })
}


exports.User = User;
exports.validateUser = validateUser;
exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```